# How to display div based on array in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a grid of images and when you clicked on a div (which also has a id), it gets the class "active". Then I put the id's of the divs that got the class 'active' into a sessionStorage array.

On the next page I want to read out which id's have been stored in my sessionStorage and want to display specific divs.

For example, array contains id 'banner', class banner gets visible.

My code so far:

```
 var sections = $.map($(".active"), function(n, i){
    return n.id;
  });

  sessionStorage.setItem("sections", JSON.stringify(sections));

  var storedSections = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("sections"));
```

This is to put the id's into an array.

I can read them out with this, in my .html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('sections');
</script>
```

The result is something like:

```
["header","banner","footer"]
```

But how do I display certain divs, depending on the result above?

Comment: Do you want to only use jQuery? AngularJs would be able to handle this quite cleanly by using ng-show.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a complete product and since I have more experience in jQuery than in Angular so I decided to go that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` method is turn an array of string (id list) and you set it in your session storage. If you want to set active class on these divs you can use these array like these:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('sections')).forEach(function(id){
      $('#'+id).addClass('active');
   })
});
```

Comment: This is the solution that works for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so, iterating over the array you received from the storage:

```js
var divs = ["div_1", "div_3"];
divs.forEach( function (div){

  /* JavaScript approach */
  var elem = document.getElementById(div);
  elem.style.display = 'block';
  
  /* jQuery approach */
  $("#" + div).show();
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_1">Hello 1</div>
<div id="div_2">Hello 2</div>
<div id="div_3">Hello 3</div>
```

Comment: will be a good idea to use a class to apply the css, else it will hide all the div

Comment: It says that divs.forEach isn't a function

Answer (score 0):

```
var sections = sessionStorage.getItem('sections');
$(sections).each(function(value) {
     $("#" + sections[value]).show();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lbzbztwa/